# Overloading vs Hiding c++

Tags: c++

a theoretical question - can an inner definition function overload an outer definition?
For example:

```
int foo(){
    class x{ 
    public:
        int foo() { return 1; } 
        int bar() { return foo(); }
    }
return 0;
}
```

The inner foo hides the outer one in class x. Can someone give an example of an inner function **overloading** an outer function, and not hiding it?

Thank you!

Comment: Define the terms "inner function" and "outer function". They don't appear in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean whether a **member function** can overload a **namespace scope function**.

The word **overload** here essentially means that two or more functions with different signatures (number of arguments and/or their types) are <del>accessible</del> visible to name lookup, and have the same name.

I don't think it's possible to overload so that the same unqualified name can stand for either member function or namespace scope function depending on arguments. E.g.,

```
#include <cmath>        // std::sin

struct S
{
    void sin() const { cout << "By Odin!" << endl; }

    void foo()
    {
        using std::sin;
        sin( 3.14 );            // OK.
        //sin()                 !Will not find the member func.
    }
};
```

Conversely, without the `using` declaration the member function can be called unqualified, but not the namespace scope function.

Answer (score 1):

Function overloading means that you have two functions with the same name, but different parameters. You could have a function `foo(int a)` and then define a function `foo(double a)` without hiding the other one.

Comment: even if foo(double) is defined inside foo(int)?

Comment: @DanDv Yes. Functions with the same name but different parameters have absolutely no connection to each other.